# Convergence of $a_n$ to $(a_1a_2)^{\frac1{3}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If a sequence of positive integers $a_n$ satisfies $a_n=\sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}$, then how can we show that $a_n\to(a_1a_2)^{\frac1{3}}$?

I am unable to start the problem. The difference equation is non-linear with no hint of even whether the sequence converges. How  do we proceed in this problem? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: I don't think that that sequence can stay as integers for very long. Do you mean positive real numbers?

Comment: @Arthur If we replace integers with positive reals, the statement becomes false  for most $a_1,a_2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I hadn't looked into the actual problem, but it seems you're right (my gut said $(a_1a_2^2)^{1/3}$ from the beginning anyway, but I still haven't actually gone through the calculations). I guess there could be a typo in the answer key.

Comment: There definitely is an homogeneity problem, and even taking $a_1=a_2=2$ (for instance), which gives the constant sequence satisfying the relation, shows that the answer must have different powers...

Comment: Please [search with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a_n%3D%5Csqrt%7Ba_%7Bn-1%7Da_%7Bn-2%7D%7D%24), this has been asked and answered many times.